# jquery serialize a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, serialization

I have this form:
http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/Pt6LQ/

The problem is that I am not be able to serialize the content form in json format whit the function serializeArray.

In the function a array is still empty.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a form element to be serialized, its "name" attribute must be defined. Add the names and it should be ok.

From [jQuery Serialize Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

> the element cannot be disabled and must contain a name attribute.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/Pt6LQ/7/ I have done but the problem is still remaining

Comment: Your form id is "frm" but in jQuery you request: $('#form'). Check that.